# what does this code do? and how it will look on dart?

Tags: c, dart

```
   hour = (bufm[1] &= ~((1 << 7) | (1 << 6) | (1 << 5)));
```

I did not understand what this code does and therefore I cannot translate it into dart. I see that there are bitwise shifts

Comment: This is also valid Dart code.

Comment: `<<` is the "shift left" operator. `|` is the bitwise OR operator, `&` is the bitwise AND operator and `~` is the bitwise NOT operator. Any C book or documentation explains this. For example https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: Does it help if you split it into two statements? `hour = bufm[1] & ~((1 << 7) | (1 << 6) | (1 << 5)); bufm[1] = hour;`

Comment: Hint (in case you haven't found out by yourself in the meantime) : `1 << x` is equivalent to "2 raised to the power of x".

Comment: Short answer (assuming `bufm[1]` and `hour` are unsigned, 8-bit types), the code clears the top 3 bits of the former and assigns that value to the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&=` means take only the bits that are set to 1 in both operands

`~` reverses all bits,

`<<` moves the bits to the left n times,

`|` combines bits from operands

so

```
hour = (bufm[1] &= ~((1 << 7) | (1 << 6) | (1 << 5))); // 128, 64, 32
hour = (bufm[1] &= ~(128 | 64 | 32)); // ~0x000000E0, reverse bits
hour = (bufm[1] &= 0xFFFFFF1F); // keep only those bits, ie. remove bits 5 6 7
```

I assume hour is an int (32 bits).
It removes bit 5, 6 and 7 from `bufm[1]` and stores it in `hour`.